# Best way to marshal an array of structures from C++ to C# (mono)

Tags: c#, c++, mono, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a structure which is of the the format

```
struct node {
    int vertices[10000];
    float normals[10000];
    int triangles[10000];
    vertex points[10000];
    int normalsCount;
    int pointsCount;
};
```

I have been able to pInvoke / marshal the structure with properties in some cases, but am wondering what would be the best practice of creating an array of 'nodes' and them passing them through to C# through DLLImport.

Any help would be appreciated! As a C++ noob this has been a very daunting task!

Comment: That's going to be astoundingly expensive with those fixed length arrays. Before continuing I think you should redesign your data structure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah good point. I'm only looking at ever requiring < 100 nodes, so I figured it would suffice. However, I might as well do it right the first time.